# Make an object collection and rotate it and it to the scene

Tags: three.js

If I add all my objects to an array

```
cube.push(new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(20,20,20), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x202020,wireframe: true}) ));
```

How can I do something like this?

```
cube.rotation.y += 20;
```

edit: I just tried `scene.add(cube);` and it didn't work so looks like that isn't the way to build a collection or set of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this pattern:

```
var object = new THREE.Object3D();

object.add( mesh1 );
object.add( mesh2 );

scene.add( object );
```

Then in the render loop,

```
object.rotation.y += 0.01;
```

three.js r.59

Comment: Thanks, seems basic but I did try google, but very difficult to find info on this